# VideoView DragShadowBuilder doesn't display shadow

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

**I have an issue with DragShadowBuilder.**

I have a VideoView which can be drag and drop, I track the comportement, I know where I drop my VideoView,... But there is no display for the user. He can take the VideoView which doesn't move on screen.

I have set a OnTouchListener which override onTouch.

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            findViewById(R.id.button_delete).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            if (view instanceof VideoView) {
                ((VideoView) view).pause();
            }

            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why the VideoView doesn't follow the finger.

Have you any idea how I can make it work ?

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

VideoView DragShadowBuilder will not show , if you want to show to the user that the video is moving then add Xml drawable to the VideoView.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/transparant"/>
            <stroke android:color="#3d61cc" android:width="2dp"></stroke>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/videostopicon"
       />
</layer-list>
```

and @drawable/videostopicon will be[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, after I have added the drawable attribute in my VideoView, nothing is shown when I drag the video.

Comment: Can you please share me the code so that i will get know why it is not working. i faced the same issue after adding drawable at runtime before and after dragging the issue got solved.

Comment: This is the XML : 
<VideoView
         android:layout_width="75dp"
         android:layout_height="75dp"
         android:layout_below="@+id/title"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
         android:id="@+id/video_view_video"
         android:drawable="@drawable/ic_movies" />

Comment: onTouchListener
@Ove
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (view instanceof VideoView) {
                ((VideoView) view).pause();
                mVideoFrom = (VideoView) view;
            }
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

Comment: onDragListener
@Over
        public bo...) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case (...)
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                    if (view instanceof VideoView){
                        ((VideoView) view).start();
                    }
                default:
                    break;
            }
     return true;
     }
}

Comment: VideoView video_view_video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_view_video);
        video_view_video.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.videobg);            add this line of code in onCreate method once you declare the Videoview

Comment: Thank you for your help.
It seems to work, but there is another issue now. I have the background over the video, I will search a solution to correct it, but if you have it before, thanks

Comment: Ok I found a solution, I just put this : video_view_video.setZOrderOnTop(true); Thanks a lot !